# Sacar elementos de una lista en R

Tags: r

Tengo una lista que esta compuesto por 1000 `data.frame` (réplicas), donde cada uno de los `data.frame` esta compuesto por 16 filas y 22 columnas

Y quiero crear listas donde:
La lista 1: este compuesta por los valores de la columna 1 y fila 1 de todas las réplicas.
Lista dos: este compuesta por los valores de la columna 1 y fila 2
Listas tres: columnas 1 fila 3
Así sucesivamente con todas las filas y columnas

Si hago lo siguiente `mdresult[[1]]$cork_est[[1]]`, donde `mdresul` se refiere a la lista donde están los 1000 `data.frame` y `cork_est` al nombre de la primera columna. El resultado que obtengo es de la réplica 1 el primer valor (fila 1) de la columna `cork_est` que se refiere a la primera columna.

Comment: Hola Delia, en general (y en este caso) ayuda a ayudar que incorpores a la pregunta un breve ejemplo de tus datos. Un `dput()` de los dos primeros elementos de tu lista servirían, si los datos se pueden hacer públicos. Con `dput(mdresult[c(1,2)])` deberían salir. Por lo que entiendo estás tratando de obtener como output una lista en la que cada elemento será unitario, una lista con los cada fila de la columna 1. Podrías probar colapsando tu lista a un único data.frame con `dplyr::bind_rows()` y después pasar la columna 1 a lista con `split()`. Mejor edita la pregunta con los datos!

Answer (score 3):

Delia, la idea de crear [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) tal como te comenta mpaladino es fundamental para los que estamos del otro lado, por un lado para entender el problema y por otro nos ahorra muchas dificultades. Por suerte, en **R**, reproducir tu ejemplo es muy sencillo. Mencionas una lista de 1000 elementos, dónde cada uno es un `data.frame` de 22 columnas y 16 filas, algo como esto:

```
# Creamos un dataframe como el ejemplo
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:(22*16), nrow=16))
df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)),1000),]
mdresult <- split(df,rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df)/16),each=16)[1:nrow(df)])
```

Si vemos el primer `data.frame` de la lista con `mdresult[[1]]`:

```
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7  X8  X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22
1   1 17 33 49 65 81  97 113 129 145 161 177 193 209 225 241 257 273 289 305 321 337
2   2 18 34 50 66 82  98 114 130 146 162 178 194 210 226 242 258 274 290 306 322 338
3   3 19 35 51 67 83  99 115 131 147 163 179 195 211 227 243 259 275 291 307 323 339
4   4 20 36 52 68 84 100 116 132 148 164 180 196 212 228 244 260 276 292 308 324 340
5   5 21 37 53 69 85 101 117 133 149 165 181 197 213 229 245 261 277 293 309 325 341
6   6 22 38 54 70 86 102 118 134 150 166 182 198 214 230 246 262 278 294 310 326 342
7   7 23 39 55 71 87 103 119 135 151 167 183 199 215 231 247 263 279 295 311 327 343
8   8 24 40 56 72 88 104 120 136 152 168 184 200 216 232 248 264 280 296 312 328 344
9   9 25 41 57 73 89 105 121 137 153 169 185 201 217 233 249 265 281 297 313 329 345
10 10 26 42 58 74 90 106 122 138 154 170 186 202 218 234 250 266 282 298 314 330 346
11 11 27 43 59 75 91 107 123 139 155 171 187 203 219 235 251 267 283 299 315 331 347
12 12 28 44 60 76 92 108 124 140 156 172 188 204 220 236 252 268 284 300 316 332 348
13 13 29 45 61 77 93 109 125 141 157 173 189 205 221 237 253 269 285 301 317 333 349
14 14 30 46 62 78 94 110 126 142 158 174 190 206 222 238 254 270 286 302 318 334 350
15 15 31 47 63 79 95 111 127 143 159 175 191 207 223 239 255 271 287 303 319 335 351
16 16 32 48 64 80 96 112 128 144 160 176 192 208 224 240 256 272 288 304 320 336 352
```

Los 999 restantes son exactamente iguales. Ahora enfocándonos a tu pregunta:

- La lista 1: este compuesta por los valores de la columna 1 y fila 1 de todas las réplicas.
- Lista dos: este compuesta por los valores de la columna 1 y fila 2
- Listas tres: columnas 1 fila 3
- etc.

Una forma posible es la siguiente:

```
lista.nueva <- split(as.vector(unlist(lapply(mdresult, '[[', 1))), rep(1:16, 1000))
```

- Con `as.vector(unlist(lapply(mdresult, '[[', 1)))` hacemos: **(a)** recortamos de todos los `data.frame` de la lista, la primer columna, **(b)** convertimos todo a un único vector, nos termina quedando algo así: `<col1-fila1><col1-fila2>..<col1-fila1000>`
- Por último, con `rep(1:16, 1000)` generamos una "máscara" para recorte mediante `split()`, con lo que terminamos quedándonos con una lista de 1000 vectores, cada uno con la columna 1 completa de cada fila de la lista original.

Si vemos, por ejemplo el primer elemento de la lista inicial, podemos constatar que esta compuesto por elemento de la columna 1 de cada una de las replicas

```
lista.nueva[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  [44] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  [87] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [130] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [173] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [216] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [259] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [302] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [345] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [388] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [431] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [474] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [517] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [560] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [603] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [646] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [689] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [732] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [775] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [818] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [861] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [904] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [947] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [990] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

La solución de Patricio es muy elegante y como de costumbre no depende de ninguna librería.

Traté de buscar una más simple usando dplyr y purrr, pero no creo que haya mejorado en ese sentido: sigue generando estructuras de datos intermedias muy complejas. Hacer subconjuntos de listas es complicado.

Va el intento de todos modos:

```
library(tidyverse)       #Para transpose(), map() y as_tibble()

mdresult %>%             #La lista que creó Patricio.
  transpose() %>%        #Transpongo la lista, ahora se organiza por las columnas de los df en su interior. 22 elementos en el primer nivel. 
  .$X1 %>%               #Extraigo la columna 1, por nombre. .$cork_est en la pregunta.
  as_tibble() %>%        #Lo paso a un data.frame de 16*1000, en el que cada fila contiene las 1000 replicaciones correspondientes a la fila con el mismo índice de los data.frame que están dentro de mdresult 
  split(1:nrow(.)) %>%   #A lista de nuevo.
  map(unlist) %>%        #Simplifico cada elemento de la lista, si no lista dentro de lista.
  map(as.vector)         #Lo paso a vector, elimina los nombres de heredados de las columna X1:X1000 de que creó as_tibble()
```

## ¿Qué hace?

Las función clave es `purrr::transpose()`, que reestructura la lista de modo que los elementos internos (en este caso, las columnas de los data.frame dentro de mdresult) se conviertan en elementos externos.

De este modo logro dos cosas: dejo los datos listos para hacer el subconjunto seleccionando sólo la primer columna de los data.frame "internos" de mdresult con `.$X1`. 
Adicionalmente la lista transpuesta ya tiene el orden que requiero, están "alineadas" (virtualmente) las filas de los data.frame internos de `mdresult`.

Con `as_tibble()` esto deja de ser virtual: esta función reorganiza los elementos de la lista en columnas (*). Uso as_tibble sólo porque me resulta más fácil ver el output en pantalla, `as.data.frame()` hace lo mismo.
El resto es simplificar y eliminar los nombres, para llevar a una lista de 16 vectores de largo 1000.

Saludos,

Martín

*. ¡Los data.frame también son listas!